# Using "extends" keyword with TypeScript Generics

Tags: generics, typescript

I can't figure out why the code below results in errors. In this simple example, the `Component` class, as expected, has no issues. But the generic implementation, which explicitly defines `State` as extending from `BaseState`, doesn't seem to be sending through the typing information provided by `BaseState`, resulting in an error.

```js
interface BaseState {
    on: boolean;
    color: string;
};

class Component {
    state: BaseState;

    constructor(state: BaseState) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    setState(partialState: Partial<BaseState>) {
        this.state = { ...this.state, ...partialState };  // no error
    }

    onInput({ value }: { value: number }) {
        this.setState({ on: value > 0 });  // no error
    }
}

class GenericComponent<State extends BaseState> {
    state: State;

    constructor(state: State) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    setState(partialState: Partial<State>) {
        this.state = { ...this.state, ...partialState };  // error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }

    onInput({ value }: { value: number }) {
        this.setState({ on: value > 0 });  // error: Argument of type '{ on: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<State>'
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like spread types are not supported on generics at the moment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727

Comment: Thanks. I saw that after I posted. So that error should go away with 2.3.1 it looks like. But what about the other error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note, this is not an exact solution to the problem described above, but merely a workaround. However, it is too long to fit into a comment.**

Regarding the second error, namely "Argument of type '{ on: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial'", there has been some discussion in the community around this topic, e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12793, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13155, though I failed to find anything matching your scenario exactly.

For some reason TS does fails to infer assignability of `Partial<State>` to `Partial<BaseState>` despite the fact that `State extends BaseState`.

For example, the following piece of code results in an error.

```
class SampleClass<State extends BaseState> {
    baseState: Partial<BaseState>;

    method(state: Partial<State>): void {
        this.baseState = state; // Type 'Partial<State>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<BaseState>'.
    }
}
```

Which appears strange to me and I would suggest to submit a suggestion to TypeScript community to consider. At least they may explain if that is excepted and why.

In the particular case you've given above, I would suggest to explicitly cast the type of the partial the following way.

```
class GenericComponent<State extends BaseState> {
    state: State;

    constructor(state: State) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    setState(partialState: Partial<State>) {
        //  Some logic here
    }

    onInput({ value }: { value: number }) {
        this.setState({ on: value > 0 } as State); 
    }
}
```

As far as I see this code remains type-safe and honours the constraint on `State`.

Answer (score -1):

why not just remove the `extends` keyword ?

```
class GenericComponent {
    state: BaseState;

    constructor(state: BaseState) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    setState(partialState: Partial<BaseState>) {
        this.state = { ...this.state, ...partialState };  // error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }

    onInput({ value }: { value: number }) {
        this.setState({ on: value > 0 });  // error: Argument of type '{ on: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<State>'
    }
}
```